# How to allows /tmp file access when running robot_upstart

Tags: python, ros

I have **my_robot_ros.service** file which auto run a launch during boot.

```
[Unit]
Description="bringup my_robot_ros"
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/my_robot_ros-start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My launch file works just fine when I run it in the terminal but when it runs with my_robot_ros.service it has errors regarding permission in the folder as shown below.
[clcik image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyBkz.png)

I think it is the reason why my imageprocessing node dies or stop working. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" solution here is to structure your code so it doesn't use pre-created files in `/tmp`. By default only the file creator can modify files directly in `/tmp`. And your error happens because running a service file will run commands under a different user. The quick workaround for this would be to remove the sticky bit in the folder via: `sudo chmod -t /tmp`.

Note that I wouldn't really recommend this in general, though.